# Jquery Object looping - How to differenciate the values and assign different task, when multiple key values are same..?

Tags: jquery, object

In object, i have same keys in multiple instance, but the value is different like "string" / "object" - how to find the value and make a condition to go for different tasks..?

here is my object and try:

```
var obj = {
    "Home":"Home link",
    "Assignments":"Assignments link",
    "Explorer":"Explorer link",
    "Assignments":{
        "Projects":"Projects sub string",
        "Background Jobs":"Background sub string",
        "Workflow Engine Queue":"Workflow Engine Queue sub string",
        "Filter Engine Queue":"Filter Engine Queue sub string",
        "Quotes":"Quotes sub string",
        "Issues":"Issues sub string"
    },
    "Explorer":{
        "Term Databases":"Term Databases sub string",
        "Translation Memories":"Translation Memories sub string",
        "Personal Preferences":"Personal Preferences sub string",
        "Manage Locale":"Manage Locale sub string"
    }
}

var  objetProcess = function(){
    $.each(obj, function(key, value){
        console.log(key,$.type(value));
    })
}

objetProcess();
```

I am looking to loop the entire object and find the value is "string" or "object" - and set the task accordingly.

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qS6H2/)

Comment: It seems like you already have the solution as you're using `$.type()` to get the objects' types? Inside your `$.each()` callback you can simply switch on the type, such as `if ($.type(value) == 'string') {...}`

Comment: Is your problem that you want to get the two different values for exemple for "Explorer" ? In that situation i don't think that is possible because you are overwriting the value in the object property on the second time. You will have to put different names to the keys. Think about it. if you do obj.Explorer what you should get? the string or the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have two keys of the same name in a single object. In the example above, the Explorer and Assignments keys are always going to be objects because the statement where a string value is set is followed by another statement that sets an object value.

Your easiest way out is to replace the key name with something else, or if you are trying to build something like a menu hierarchy, you'll need to create a more complex data structure to hold your information. Something like this comes to mind -

```
var menu = [{label: "Home", url: "link"},
            {label: "Assignments", url: "link",
             children: [{label: "Foo", url: "link"}, {label: "Bar", url: "link"}]
            },
            {label: "Explorer", url: "link",
             children: [{label: "Zac", url: "link"}, {label: "Cal", url: "link"}, {label: "Too", url: "link"}]
            }
           ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `if` condition in `objetProcess` as below:

```
var  objetProcess = function(){
    $.each(obj, function(key, value){
        if ($.type(value) === 'string') {
            console.log('string task');
        } else if ($.type(value) === 'object') {
            console.log('object task');
        }
    })
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qS6H2/5/

Comment: I did, but i am not getting the loop 1 time for 1 key.. can you update the jsfiddle please?

Comment: You are assigning values to `Assignments` and `Explorer` two times, last value will overwrite earlier value